How to Fix AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'exceptions' Traceback
Exception has occurred:
AttributeError
module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'exceptions'
File "/Users/shrikantpadhy/Desktop/SWA-ENGINE/gateai-preplanning-engine/runner/main.py", line 8, in \<module\>
import boto3
AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'exceptions'

I am using

python == 3.11.5
boto3==1.34.140
botocore==1.34.140

I tried reinstalling the boto3 and botocore libraries, I also tried shifting to different python versions still facing the same issue.

What makes you think the problem is caused by a broken installation or a wrong Python version and not by your code?

You should read https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html#upgrading-to-1-11-0 "The vendored versions of requests and urllib3 are no longer being used and have been replaced with a direct dependency on upstream urllib3 and requests is no longer a dependency of botocore. While these vendored dependencies are still in the botocore package they should not be used as they will be removed in the future."

i have resolved the issue, it was due to absence of urllib3 library in my system.
